# Groovy: How to define float numbers that would generate output as 2 digit decimal points

Tags: groovy, jmeter

Algo is to generate random numbers but in form of 2 decimal points like 4.78, 3.88, etc

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round a float value using [DecimalFormat class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) like:

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat('#.##').format(yourFloat)
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter round float]

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter

Answer (score 1):

If you return a `BigDecimal`, you can tell it how many digits it handles.  E.g.:

```
println(new BigDecimal(0.666).setScale(2, java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP))
// => 0.67
```

Only do this at the very end of your calculations.